# Multi-computer distributed operations using QGIS

Tags: qgis, network, viewshed, multithreading

Although QGIS is multithreaded for some operations, There are many cases where I run large operations for cumulative viewsheds which take an extremely long time to calculate.

Is there a process implemented in QGIS to distribute the work load accross multiple netowkred computers, and return the results back to one machine?

For example, like multi threading but accross multiple machines.

Comment: Would breaking up your process to several processes (like focused viewsheds for a limited area) and than stick together the results be an option? Of course, just as a workaround - hopefully there will be a proper answer to your interesting question!

Comment: If you wish to explore other software then please write separate questions for each so this does not become a poll of software options.

Comment: Can you run your analyses completely in python? If so, look at dask distributed clusters.

Comment: Yes, I can run it completely in python.
After looking at dask distributed clusters I kept searching and started reading about HPC Clusters and Open-MPI.

Comment: I'm not sure how the 2 approaches, open-mpi vs dask clusters would differ in the end result. 

I have found in some searches that gdal may have been run at universities on a HPC clusters but I'm not sure how they set it up etc. Any information regarding how to set this up using existing methods before programming my own basic and likely limited implementation, would be helpful.